# Is there any way to get snow layers to light up properly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've recently been trying to terraform a mountain area using snow layers. However, even in full sunlight, there are weird shadows cropping up making the sides of the blocks seem much darker.

[image]

These ugly dark patches are particularly noticable from a distance:

[image]

The only thing I've been able to work out so far is that it seems to be effected by solid blocks in the vacinity:

[image]

[image]

What's going on here and is there any way I can get rid of this unsightly artifact?

Comment: I have now spent 10 minutes scrolling back and forth between your screenshots and i still have honestly no idea what dark artifacts you're referring to. The last two images, for example I don't see any difference except the dirt block you've placed in the second. Can you maybe circle one of these artifacts in one of your screenshots so it's clear what you're referring to?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Ok I'll try to get better examples when I get the chance

Comment: I mean, if you could just take one of those screenshots and draw a circle around one of the dark areas you're concerned about that's be great. Honestly the only dark shadows I'm seeing are the ones along the sides of the blocks which I'd expect in a cuboid 3d environment like this.